# why is handleEvent taking so much time when inserting divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

according to the chrome profiler handleEvent takes up ~90% of the time when i do div_el.innerHTML = "html with hundreds of simple divs". what is handleEvent doing? i use jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div_el.innerHTML = html;` with *hundreds of simple divs* takes ages because of the number of writes to the DOM
 - which are very slow compared with assembling them 'offline' (as a simple string or such) and writing them all to the DOM in one fell swoop.

Take a look at http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

From the above (under **Minimize DOM Access**):

> Accessing DOM elements with JavaScript
>   is slow so in order to have a more
>   responsive page, you should:
>
> - Cache references to accessed elements
> - **Update nodes "offline" and then add    them to the tree**
> - Avoid fixing layout with JavaScript

Comment: thanks. what do they mean by updating nodes offline and then adding them to the tree? it seems strange that all the dom access is inside handleEvent. what is handleEvent doing?